# Why does RN use setState when it functions just like forceUpdate

Tags: react-native

Please have a Look at this very simple example

```
'use strict';
var React = require('react-native');
var {
    AppRegistry, Text, TextInput, View
} = React;
var bString = 'b init';
var Example = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            aString: 'a init',
            cString: 'c init'
        };
    },
    changedString: function(aEvent) {
        bString = 'b changed';
        this.state.cString = 'c changed';
        this.setState((state) => {
            return {
                aString: 'a changed'
            };
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                <Text>
                    {this.state.aString}{'\r\n'}{bString}{'\r\n'}{this.state.cString}
                </Text>
                <Text onPress={this.changedString}>
                    Ppppppppppppppppppppp......press me
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    },
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Project16N', () => Example);
```

I thought only `aString` on the mobile's screen while be changed when `changedString` is called. but when `changedString` is called, `aString`,`bString`,`CString` both changed. So why do we use `this.setState( balabala...)`?

why don't we just use `this.forceUpdate` instead?

Where is the difference between `setState` and `forceUpdate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're modifying the `cString` object from within your `changedString` function.

As a rule of thumb you should never modify anything on `this.state` directly, you should treat it as immutable, and instead use `this.setState()` to modify state since the mutation you just made might be overridden when using `this.setState` at a later stage and it usually makes it harder to reason about your application when you're mutating state directly.

The [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) have a good way of explaining it.

Comment: Why shouldn't I modify anything on this.state directly?